# Does Firebase Observer uses Internet bandwidth EveryTime we call it in viewWillAppear? Even if there were no changes in the Data?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I basically want to call my Observer everytime my view appears and remove it when the view disappears, but I'm not sure about how it will affect the bandwidth?

Comment: In general you *add* an observer to firebase. Adding an observer will fire an event to retrieve data from Firebase and present it as a snapshot to your app. The bandwidth would be determined by how much data is returned; i.e. if the observer is .value on your root reference, everything in your database would be returned which *could* be a lot of data. Without details there's really no way to answer specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how you attach the observer and what other code you have that interacts with the Firebase Database. Since you didn't share that, I'll describe a bit how the Firebase client works.

- When you attach an observer to a location, the Firebase client starts synchronizing the data for that location from the server.
- The first time you add an observer, this means that it will have to read the data from the server. It keeps this data in an internal cache and optionally (if you've [enabled persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence)) on disk.
- But if you when add a second observer to that same location, the data is already available, so it won't be re-downloaded.
- Once you remove the last observer from a location, the data will for that location will be removed from Firebase's cache. If you after that attach a new listener, it will have to re-read the data from the Firebase servers.